# presetOverride when creating Azure Media Services v3 Job

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

When creating an Azure Media Services Job via the REST API, I cannot set a `presetOverrides` property on the `JobOutputAsset` as defined in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/jobs/create#joboutputasset

My request body is:

```json
{
 "properties": {
    "input": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobInputAsset",
      "assetName": "inputAsset"
    },
    "outputs": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset",
        "assetName": "outputAsset",
        "label": "en-US",
        "presetOverride": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.AudioAnalyzerPreset",
            "audioLanguage": "en-US",
            "mode": "Basic"
        }
      }
    ],
    "priority" : "Normal"
 }
}
```

The error message thrown is:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidResource",
        "message": "The property 'presetOverride' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."
    }
}
```

When removing the `presetOverride` data, everything works as expected. The official documentation clearly states that the `Microsoft.Media.JobOutputAsset` does have a `presetOverride` property though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to select the correct API version when communicating with the Azure Media Services REST API.

In this case, api version `2020-05-01` from the Azure Media Services Postman examples was used. But the `presetOverride` option is only available starting with version `2021-06-01`.

Setting `api-version=2021-06-01` as a GET parameter enables Preset Overrides.

Answer (score 0):

couple of concerns here Rene.  I would not recommend using the raw REST API directly for any Azure services. Reason being is that there are a lot of built-in retry scenarios and retry policies that are already rolled into the client SDKs.  We've had many customers try to roll their own REST API library but run into massive issues in production because they failed to read up on how to handle and write their own custom retry policy code.
Unless you are really familiar with rolling your own retry policies and how Azure Resource Management gateway works, try to avoid it and just use the official client SDKs - see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#general-rest-and-retry-guidelines

Now, to answer your specific question - try using my sample here in .NET and see if it answers your question.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet/blob/3ab85647cbadd2b868aadf175afdede67b40b2fd/AudioAnalytics/AudioAnalyzer/Program.cs#L129

I can also provide a working sample of this in Node.js/Typescript in this repo if you like.  It is using the latest 10.0.0 release of our Javascript SDK.
I'm working on samples in this repo today - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials

UPDATE: Added basic audio in Typescript sample.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/AudioAnalytics/index.ts

Shows how to use the preset override per job.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the fast answer! As the PHP SDK has been retired and does not support the v3 API, I'm stuck with using the REST API... but your link might've just brought me closer to finding a solution, will try tomorrow and give feedback :)

Comment: Ah yes, PHP...  I see that the Azure SDK team has fallen out of love with PHP a bit.  Any chance you can build your backend for AMS in Node.js and call to a middle tier API from PHP?   Might be nice to use Azure Functions as mid-tier and then call it from PHP?

Comment: At least that way you get the official SDK support - and you get retry built in for long running operations, etc..

Comment: After inspecting the requests the JS SDK made and comparing them to my requests, I noticed my silly mistake - I was using the older API version from the Postman samples. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like I need to spend a few hours updating our Postman samples... they are on the older API version....

Comment: RIP to one of the nicest Azure features (imo)... good night sweet prince

Comment: @RenéRoth - thanks for using it... it was a nice feature indeed!